# Box Net: What is the pattern used and characters allowed during serach

Tags: box-api

I need to test the working of Box Net search in my application. For this I need more information about the search pattern. I see search results are compared with both file title and content.

Search is showing different behaviour when I have file names with special characters? Will search work when I have special characters as file names?

Following is the query I am using
boxSearch = client.getSearchManager().search(searchFileName, boxDefaultRequestObject);

Can you share me the pattern used during search and characters allowed and in what character combination results are seen?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources on search:
https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/200519888-How-do-I-search-for-files-and-folders-in-Box-

Box's search returns folder/file names and content, and it also accepts booleans. Just don't use mixed case (aNd is NOT okay, while AND or and is okay).

Box also accepts special characters in uploads and search. See the description here, as this was a fairly recent product update that came in mid-2013.

Additional special character support – Box will add support for more types of special characters across the Box website, desktop and mobile apps. Once the change is live, Box products will support almost all printable characters (except / \ or empty file names; also will not support leading or trailing spaces on files and folders).

Comment: We downloaded the source code from https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2. But still we face the same issue with special characters. Do you know any other link which has got the latest source code. And we see the same issue persist in the app.box.com site also. Is the Box app uses old or new jar?

Comment: Issue is like We have files with names as %&!@#$^$()-_+=;',.`~..doc and we are searching by passing "!" in search. But in output We don't see the above mentioned file.